# Why would my initialized static property be null when I access it?

Tags: c#

I have the following code ( extracted from the real code )

```
public static class AssemblyLogger {

    public static Lazy<Window> Window { get; } = new Lazy<Window>(NewWindowHandler);

    public static IScheduler Scheduler =>
        new DispatcherScheduler( Window.Value.Dispatcher );

}
```

When I call `Scheduler` I get a `NullReferenceException`. Stopping with the debugger I see

[image]

As far as I know this should be impossible. `Window` is statically initialized and read only and so any further access to it should be get only and it should never be null.

I have set a breakpoint against the initializer but it never gets hit

[image]

I have also tried a static readonly field and still the same problem

```
public static readonly Lazy<Window> Window  = new Lazy<Window>(NewWindowHandler);
```

Is it possible to have a race condition against the static initialization?

**Attempts to make an MCVE** so far are not successful. The below spec tests my minimal postable code and the real code. The MCVE one passes :( and the real one fails. I am missing some context and need further work to isolate the issue.

```
public class Tester
{
    public static class AssemblyLoggerMCVE
    {

        public static Lazy<Window> Window { get; } = new Lazy<Window>(NewWindowHandler);

        private static Window NewWindowHandler() => new Window();

        public static IScheduler Scheduler =>
            new DispatcherScheduler(Window.Value.Dispatcher);

    }

    /// This passes
    [StaFact]
    public void AssemblyLoggerMCVEShouldWork()
    {
        AssemblyLoggerMCVE.Scheduler.Should().NotBeNull();

    }

    /// This fails
    [StaFact]
    public void AssemblyLoggerShouldWork()
    {
        AssemblyLogger.Scheduler.Should().NotBeNull();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the old school getter? This looks like a bug though.

Comment: Getter will not work as Lazy will not be cached and I will get many windows popping up.

Comment: But I have updated the question to show that the same problem occurs with a static readonly field so it's not specifically the getter. I'm so sure this is impossible I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Photoshop. Unless you show [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you try adding an empty `static` ctor to your example and see if that causes it to work?

Comment: @Kirk I added that. Made no difference. Initially all the init code was in a static constructor when I stumbled across this problem. I moved all init code inline assuming that maybe that would fix the problem. It didn't

Comment: @Sinatr Are you suggesting I photoshopped the error in order to go point mining??

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, yep .

Comment: @Sinatr It's not a bad idea though ;)  Next time!

Comment: Is your "NewWindowHandler" working correctly ?

Comment: @D.J. The call to ``new Lazy<Window>(NewWindowHandler)`` is never made so even if it had bugs it would be an independent problem. ( I set a breakpoint to check ) See question for image

Comment: I am suggesting you to spend some time on MCVE. Obviously this can't happens under *normal* conditions. And you didn't post enough code to consider what could be the reason. I am curious in answer, but the question as it is poor: "here is a cut from my project, please guess why it doesn't work how it should".

Comment: @Sinatr I agree with you totally. I'll see what I can do but I'm not hopeful when taken out of the wild the bug/error will be apparent.

Comment: I found the problem. I will replicate the error in an answer and post it. It was my fault but the error is subtle.

Comment: No. I didn't figure it out. I can create a test case that generates the same type of error but it is contrived and not clear that it is the same problem. I've tried to MCVE the question as @Sinatr suggested. I've updated the question but the attempt to reduce the complexity of the code also removes the error. I'll spend some more time and report back later.

Comment: For reference the contrived test case is https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/bacc5ce6388ea48b182532783f2a438a but it requires out of order specification of one static in terms of another which I'm fairly sure is not my current case.

Comment: Cracked it. This time I am sure it is my fault. Stupid circular static initialization error. I'll add the answer. Thanks @Sinatr for pushing me to MCVE :)

Answer (score 2):

The error can be clearly replicated by the following test case which has more context than the question suggested was necessary.

```
public class Tester
{
    public class AssemblyLoggerControlModel
    {
        public static IScheduler S = AssemblyLoggerMCVE.Scheduler;
    }

    public class AssemblyLogger
    {

        public static AssemblyLoggerControlModel ModelInstance { get; } = 
            new AssemblyLoggerControlModel();

        public static readonly Lazy<Window> Window =
            new Lazy<Window>(NewWindowHandler);

        private static Window NewWindowHandler() => new Window();

        public static IScheduler Scheduler => 
            new DispatcherScheduler(Window.Value.Dispatcher);

    }


}
```

There is a **circular dependency** between static initializers. Static initialization of static property `AssemblyLogger.ModelInstance` causes static property `AssemblyLoggerControlModel.S` to be intitialized which then tries to call the static `AssemblyLogger.Scheduler` method which in turn tries to access `Window` which because the static initialization for AssemblyLogger is not complete is still null.

Basically my code is pure evil and the best thing to do is

[image]